# error en fórmula hipervinculo en excel

Tags: excel, funciones, office365

Buen día:
Acabo de detectar algo muy, pero muy raro.
 Creé en una hoja los siguiente:
Paso 1:
Nos posicionamos en la primera celda donde queremos pegar la lista
(la columna del lado derecho debe estar vacía)
Ir a la pestaña fórmulas
Allí ir a utilizar en la fórmula
al fondo de la lista dice "Pegar nombres"
Nos abre un cuadro de diálogo
Seleccionamos el botón Pegar lista
- Esto nos crea una lista en dos columnas
- la primera es el nombre que tiene el rango
- la segunda es la dirección 'Hoja'!CeldaInicio:CeldaFinal

Paso 2:
-  Creamos un Hipervínculo (¡vamos un enlace!)
- nos posicionamos el la celda correspondiente en la tercera columna (por ejemplo C16)
- Escribimos =HIPERVINCULO(
"" nos aparece debajo de la fórmula los datos que tenemos que poner""
 * primer dato escribimos el nombre que obtuvimos en la primera columna
(truco al empezar a escribirlo nos abre un desplegable  y lo podemos elegir ahí y lo aceptamos con "tabulador")
 * escribimos ; (punto y coma) o lo que nos pida la ayuda
  Esto nos posiciona en el segundo dato.
 * volvemos ha repetir el paso anterior y escribimos " (comillas dobles) delante y detrás.
- ACEPTAMOS la fórmula o simplemente le damos al tabulador.
- Repetimos esto para todos los nombres de la lista.
- seleccionamos las celdas que acabamos de crear
- Y les aplicamos el formato que queramos.
¡Y ya está lista nuestra lista!
Si quieres rizar el rizo
la puedes convertir en una lista personalizada.
Y me funciona bien, pero si la formula está en las primeras filas de la hoja me salta #ERROR
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Las fórmulas como se ve están bien ¡No sé que pasa!
¿Alguna ayuda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ese error suele darse con cálculos, en este caso lo que se supone hay en la formula es una referencia a un nombre de rango, abría que revisar si realmente es una formula de hipervinculo.

Una buena opción es comprobar las formulas, puede hacerlo seleccionando la celda que tiene la formula con error, luego en la barra de formulas de click en `Fx` "**Insertar función**" ( igual se puede hacer con `SHIFT+F3`), así podrá ver que argumento de la formula genera el error.

Otro método es seleccionar la celda de la formula, ir al menú formulas y dar click en "**Evaluar formula**", cada vez que de click en evaluar, se evaluara la parte de la formula que este subrayada antes.

Adicional a lo anterior, sugiero ver en la pagina siguiente algunas opciones para solucionar ese error.
https://support.office.com/es-es/article/c%C3%B3mo-corregir-un-error-%C2%A1valor-error-15e1b616-fbf2-4147-9c0b-0a11a20e409e

Comment: ¡Gracias! He detectado que en esas filas, en otra hoja las tenía inmovilizadas, al movilizarlas se corrigió el problema. Así que debió ser eso.

Answer (score 0):

Hipervínculo permite un número máximo de caracteres, 32K
Supongo que internamente sí los llena, aunque a nosotros nos despliegue pocos.

Como algunos hipervínculos sí se muestran y otros no, lo más seguro es que estás muy cerca del límite.

- Prueba eliminando caracteres
- Descubre, con =LARGO() cuál es el límite para ti, de caracteres
- Mantén la cuenta en una celda y cuando suceda, modifica tus valores

Es muy molesto porque no permite automatizar

[https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/office/especificaciones-y-l%C3%ADmites-de-excel-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3#:~:text=Entre%20200%20y%20250%2C%20seg%C3%BAn%20el%20idioma%20de,c%C3%A1lculo.%2065%20530.%20Paneles%20en%20una%20ventana.%204](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/office/especificaciones-y-l%C3%ADmites-de-excel-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3#:%7E:text=Entre%20200%20y%20250%2C%20seg%C3%BAn%20el%20idioma%20de,c%C3%A1lculo.%2065%20530.%20Paneles%20en%20una%20ventana.%204).